# How to split a string into columns by a specific length (and not delimiter)

Tags: string, oracle, plsql, split, string-length

How to split a string into columns by a specific length (and not delimiter)
for example, the string is a 40000 character query and I need to split it into 3000 character strings and then run replace operation in it because the string has "$ in it and I need to replace them with certain replaceable characters

```
select $, $ from (select $,$ from where ...... id=$ .......
...
..
....
order by $)
```

Now I need to replace $ with my specific values.. I tried but it is not returning the full 40000 length query because of buffer.

Comment: have you tried SUBSTR( string, start_position [, length ] )?

Comment: please provide more details with example.

Comment: Hi thanks for reaching out I just want to split a string with 40000 characters into smaller strings with 2000/3000 characters all in different dynamic variables or table column values.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way:

```
select regexp_substr('qwertyuioplkjhgfdsazxcvbnm', '.{1,6}',1,level) as mini_str_len_6 
from dual
CONNECT by LEVEL <= regexp_count('qwertyuioplkjhgfdsazxcvbnm', '(.{1,6})');
```

Result:

```
qwerty
uioplk
jhgfds
azxcvb
nm
```